# What is the difference between Future Continuous and Present Continuous?

Tags: present-continuous

I heard that natives use Present Cont. to describe things in the future.
As I understood, we use Present Cont. when we have arranged an action or there is at least one person with whom we agreed to have plans.

But I saw this:

1. I am teaching English tomorrow.
2. I will be teaching English tomorrow.

**What is the difference and when I should use Present Cont. to describe action in the future?**

Comment: Please use the search bar and look for "future continuous present continuous future". I'm pretty sure it's been answered here several times already.

Comment: The biggest difference is that #1 is only "future" because of the word ***tomorrow***. The actual *verb* form is the same regardless of whether the intended sense is current or future. And the same applies with the non-continuous form - Present: ***I work here today***, Future: ***I work here tomorrow***.

Comment: You would be _more_ likely to use the present continuous in the context of a conversation about your timetable, or when telling someone what your commitments are during the coming week - but there isn't a strict rule about it.

Answer (score -3):

"I'm teaching English tomorrow," thought technically incorrect, is an acceptable colloquialism, especially in a conversation.

The same applies to the present tense used to describe something in the past, as in:

"Last week, I'm walking down the street, not bothering anyone, and suddenly this lady comes up to me and says ..."

"I will be teaching English tomorrow" is grammatically correct.

Comment: It's not "technically incorrect"; it's a standard construction and perfectly good English.  What's your source for this being wrong?

Comment: And the "Last week..." sentence is also grammatically correct. It's called the "**historical present**".

Comment: @alphabet:  What is your source for "2+2=5" being wrong?

Comment: Okay, so, should the OP example be called "futuristic present" or something?

Comment: @Ricky My source, Huddleston & Pullum's *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language,* calls this construction the **futurate,** though of course the terminology differs between sources. Compare sentences like "The sun sets at 8pm tonight" or "Our flight leaves tomorrow." There are a number of rules about where this can and can't be used.

Comment: @alphabet: Does common sense apply, or is it no longer in fashion?

Comment: "Correct" English is defined by what people ***actually say***, not by "common sense".

Comment: This isn't even some sort of informal or casual usage; it's just basic English grammar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Some people say "I could care less." Some people aren't very bright.

Comment: That's at [least tens if not hundreds of millions of Americans](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+could+care+less%2CI+couldn%27t+care+less&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) you're trashing! It's been [kicked around on ELU for 13 years now....](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/706/)

Comment: ...but I've only just come across this: [Stephen Pinker claimed that could care less is not just a colloquial phrase meaning couldn't care less, because "The melodies and stresses are completely different, and for a good reason. The second version is not illogical, it's sarcastic".](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001201.html) Akin to *"That's positively riveting, but now let's talk about something even more interesting. **Me**!"*